# Non-Native function returning an array - How to display the output

Tags: arrays, excel

I apologise if this is a very simple question, but I am at a bit of a loss here.

A bespoke formula I want to use returns an array of values, as seen here:
[image]

But I cannot find a way to present this output in a cell separated format, only the first cell (39478) is returned.

There is a note included in the documentation: *Hint: This function is a multiple result function. You MUST set an array for the output.*

Whilst I understand I am going to need an array to display multiple results, I cannot find the method of doing so. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **bespoke formula** wants to return an array of values, there are a couple of ways to get the results into multiple cells.

1. Put the formula into a cell and hit <kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Next, select that cell along with several cells below it. Tap <kbd>F2</kbd> then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. The successive values should fill the cells selected until an error (no more returns) is reached.
2. Put that formula into a cell and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. The formula should be wrapped in *braces* (e.g. **{** and **}**). If the correct relative and absolute cell addresses were used (e.g. **$**A**$**1** or **$**A1**, etc) then you should be able to fill, copy or drag down the formula into successive rows.
3. Use an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to contain the array of returned values from the bespoke formula and peel off successive values using the *row_num* parameter. 
         `=INDEX(<bespoke formula>, ROW(1:1))` 
     Filled down.

Sooner or later, you will run out of rows to fill. An [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) used as a wrapper can help avoid he display of errors.

If you want to put all of the values into a single cell, then a User defined Function (aka UDF) could concatenate the array into a single string. This last method is generally not recommended as it renders the values useless for anything other than display purposes.

---

<sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.</sub>

<sub>Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum.</sub>

<sub>See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: Thats fantastic thanks Jeeped, I cant believe I haven't come across this functionality in Excel before!
I tried all methods and the first proves the quickest and least taxing computationally.